# How to execute a javascript function from a web part control wrapped inside an UpdatePannel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, updatepanel, web-parts

I am working a SharePoint web part, which have a calendar control, now on calendar `_VisibleMonthChanged` event I am trying to call a javascript function like :

```
protected void cldEvents_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var jQueryFn = "bindScrollBar();";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Test", jQueryFn, true);
}
```

But its not happening.
(Note : the control is wrapped inside an Update Panel).

Please help achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just try putting simple alert in jQueryFn string. Like `jQueryFn = "alert('test');"`

Comment: @Ali.NET I tried, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `RegisterStartupScript` call should be like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatePanel, updatePanel.GetType(), "Test", jQueryFn, true);
```

Here you are passing page reference instead of UpdatePanel's.